# Problem displaying data when sorting

Tags: sort

I'm trying to output a custom field from a channel that stores a formatted date, which gets used for a jQuery datepicker.

I'm using the following code;

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="events" dynamic="no" orderby="url_title" sort="asc"}
["{event_date}"],
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

However, I've noticed a problem in that it won't output entries that have a date like 4-9-13. The {event_date} custom field is a simple text field.

It seems to be fine for dates stored like; 1-8-13, 12-8-13, 24-8-13, 2-9-13, 3-9-13, 30-9-13 etc - but it just won't output any dates that start with a number 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 or 9.

I wondered if anyone knows a way around this?

Thank you.

Comment: When you say "it" won't output entries, do you mean your template (looking at the source code of the page, that is), or your datepicker widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was the silent limit of 100 from EE that was preventing them being displayed. So I just added a limit="200" to fix it.